# How to switch between main, light and dark variances of a Material-UI Palette

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Assuming I am using a Material-UI palette as follows:

```
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#039be5",
      light: "#63ccff",
      dark: "#C218006db35B",
      contrastText: "#fafafa"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#f50057",
      light: "#ff5983",
      dark: "#bb002f",
      contrastText: "#f9fbe7"
    },
    error: {
      main: "#f50057",
      light: "#ff5983",
      dark: "#bb002f",
      contrastText: "#f9fbe7"
    }
  },
```

And let's say that I am using a number of Material-UI components such as the `<AppBar />`, `<Button />`, etc. and each of them I want to give them different accents of the primary palette object - ex. `<AppBar />` will be `primary.main` and `<Button />` will be `primary.light`.

How can I do it?

Using something like `<AppBar position="static" color="primary.light">` does not work, and throws an error.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem; want to use "primary.light". I'm not getting an error, but my button is greyed out.

Comment: Using `style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.light }}` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the docs are unclear.
Here is the only hacky work-around I found:

```
<AppBar position="static" className="primaryLight">

const styles = theme => ({
  primaryLight: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light
  }
}
```

This library is convoluted... at least it's consistent with React!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't set `color` prop to `"primary.light"`. The error that you've mentioned tells that `color` prop expects one of `["default","inherit","primary","secondary"].` To achieve desired coloring for your `<AppBar />` and `<Button />` you could apply some styles:

   ```
   style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main }}
   ```
2. To change the palette itself, you could keep track of `activePalette` inside of your `redux` store or components state. Here is simple example using state:

```js
const {createMuiTheme,MuiThemeProvider,AppBar,Button,Typography} = window['material-ui'];

const THEME = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    list: ["primary", "secondary", "error"],
    primary: {
      id: 0,
      main: "#039be5",
      light: "#63ccff",
      dark: "#C21800",
      contrastText: "#fafafa"
    },
    secondary: {
      id: 1,
      main: "#f50057",
      light: "#ff5983",
      dark: "#bb002f",
      contrastText: "#f9fbe7"
    },
    error: {
      id: 2,
      main: "#bb002f",
      light: "#f9fbe7"
    }
  }
});

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activePaletteId: THEME.palette.primary.id
  };

  get activePaletteName() {
    return THEME.palette.list[this.state.activePaletteId];
  }

  get activePalette() {
    return THEME.palette[this.activePaletteName];
  }

  nextPalette = () => {
    this.setState(s => ({
      activePaletteId: ++s.activePaletteId % THEME.palette.list.length
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppBar 
          position="static" 
          style={{ 
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginBottom: '20px',
            backgroundColor: this.activePalette.main }}
        >
          <Typography 
            style={{ color: '#fff' }}
            variant="subheading"
          >
            Palette: {this.activePaletteName}
          </Typography>
        </AppBar>
        <Button
          variant="raised"
          onClick={this.nextPalette}
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.activePalette.light }}
        >
          Change palette
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={THEME}>
   <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>, 
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Answer (score -3):

You can overwrite what will be the "default" (or any other) color for lets say, AppBar with your theme:

```
   overrides:{
    MuiAppBar: {
      colorDefault: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      }
    }
   }
```

It really helps to go to documentation -> components API -> implementation of the component. There you will be able to see how component set up and what can you override/change with Theme/Styles etc.

Comment: Not provided the solution - of how to use variant light dark or color contrast